# bash script doesn't executed command on a file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, exec, executable

i'm using ubuntu LTS 20.04, i have a textfile with over 90.000 line, if I executed the command `ipset add geoblock 7.7.7.7/24` on cli it works. My testfile test.sh is executable and readable ( rx) and and looks like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ipset add geoblock 23.21.22.22/24 
 ipset add geoblock 21.22.33.22/32 
 ipset  add geoblock 11.22.33.44/32
 ipset add ........ ..... ..... ..
```

But my bash doesn't execute anything and get thousand of error like this:

```
' is invalid as numberor: '24
' is invalid as numberor: '22
' is invalid as numberor: '24
' is invalid as numberor: '23
' is invalid as numberor: '21
' is invalid as numberor: '22
' is invalid as numberor: '24
' is invalid as numberor: '23
' is invalid as numberor: '24
' is invalid as numberor: '12
' is invalid as numberor: '24
' is invalid as numberor: '28
' is invalid as numberor: '28
' is invalid as numberor: '28
' is invalid as numberor: '28
' is invalid as numberor: '28
' is invalid as numberor: '24
' is invalid as numberor: '22
```

. What i have need to change ? For every help im thanksfull.

kind regards blackbeard

Comment: no, my file doesnt include >.

Comment: If your script is called `go.sh`, try running `file go.sh`

Comment: Try also `cat -vet go.sh | more` and paste the result in your question after clicking `edit` underneath it.

Comment: can you explained it more ? like in step by step.

Comment: Your file probably has Windows style CRLF line endings; those commands will show if it does or not.

Comment: i try you first advice ( go.sh ) and get the result:
`ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`  and then executed `cat -vet go.sh | more` and get the result : 
`ipset add geo 2.16.88.0/24^M$' `ipset add geo 2.2.3.4/24^M$'` ....

Comment: You appear to have used a nasty Windows editor to write Linux code. Windows uses carriage return and linefeeds at the end of every line. Linux uses just a linefeed. You can remove the carriage returns with `tr -d '\r' < YourScript > HappyScript`

Comment: Mark setchell great thanks for your experience, after reading CRLF and looking by google i found the package dos2unix and with the command ´dos2unix go.sh´ i convert it to unix style and it works.